# Automorphisms of infinite matrix algebra

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras

This is a similar question to [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3259067/automorphisms-of-infinite-matrices) that I posted in MSE a few days ago.

I recently came across [this paper](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/110/38/15222.full.pdf) from Alahmedi, Alsulami, Jain and Zelmanov, which quoted the following result for $M_\infty(K)$, the (non-unital) $K$-algebra of countably indexed infinite matrices with finitely many nonzero entries.

> Theorem 12: For an arbitrary $K$-algebra automorphism $\alpha$ of $M_\infty(K)$, there exists some invertible column finite matrix $T$ such that $$\alpha(a) = T^{-1} a T \text{ for all } a \in M_\infty(K)$$

Nathan Jacobson's *The Structure of Rings* was cited as the location of the result, but no specific location within the book was given. Unfortunately, I was unable to find the specific result from Jacobson that the theorem in the above paper was referencing.

Over the past few days, I've been able to put together a proof for this result on my own, but I was wondering if anybody knew the specific location of this result within the book or in another resource. I want to see how far my proof differs from the proof from "The Book" so to speak.

Edit: When I say "$K$-algebra," in the above, I'm invoking a slightly weaker definition of an "algebra." Being a vector space generated by an infinite collection of matrix units, $M_\infty(K)$ has zero center, hence it is impossible to fulfill the traditional requirement that $K \subseteq Z(M_\infty(K))$

Comment: This appears to me to follow from the Skolem-Noether theorem, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I believe that the Skolem-Noether theorem depends upon the assumption that the algebra is unital (I may be reading the statement wrong however). $M_\infty(K)$ is a non-unital algebra.

Comment: Indeed, that violates the formulation of Skolem-Noether that I know.  $M_\infty(K)$ is the direct limit in the category of non-unital $K$-algebras of matrix algebras (to which Skolem-Noether applies), which feels like it should be helpful, but I don't actually see how to proceed that way.

Comment: This specific problem has been bouncing around my head for a bit now, but it was only recently that I've seen this result in the literature. My proof mocked the argument in the main lemma of [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0024379516303548) paper, which worked, but was not tidy.

Comment: the edit sounds like a complicated way to just mention it's a non-unital algebra.

Comment: The four authors of the paper you cited must know the answer. Did you ask them?